# jquery - how to set multiple arrays, assign first value and retrieve it?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm lost trying to create and populate arrays.

I have four wrapper panels, which contain div-elements with an id. The id from the div-element with data-show="first" should be set as first array entry of the respective panel-array.

Here is what I have:

```
$panels.each(function(index) {
   if ( $(this).jqmData('track') == 'history' ) {
   var nameSpace = "hist_"+$(this).jqmData('id'),
       nameSpace = [];
       nameSpace.push({
             0:'#'+$(this).find(':jqmData(show="first")').attr('id')
             });
       }
   });
```

This creates four objects, but I cannot access them using either nameSpace inside the `each` call or outside using `hist_"+$panelName[0]`

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `namespace` outside the loop.
Currently, you're initialising a `nameSpace` variable inside the each. After the declaration, the variable is immediately overwritten by an empty array `[]`, and a new entry is pushed into it. That logic is somewhat flawed.

```
//var namespace = []; //Commented the array method
var namespace = {};//Declare an OBJECT to allow alphanumeric names
$panels.each(function(index) {
   if ( $(this).jqmData('track') == 'history' ) {
       var id = "hist_"+$(this).jqmData('id');
       namespace[id] = ['#'+$(this).find(':jqmData(show="first")').attr('id')];
       //namespace.push(['#'+$(this).find(':jqmData(show="first")').attr('id')]);
       //Or:
       //namespace.push('#'+$(this).find(':jqmData(show="first")').attr('id'));

   }
});
```

The commented code shows methods to refer through the created data through an array. The current code results in a `namespace` variable in this format:

```
namespace = {
    'hist_someID': ['#...ID'],
    'hist_anotherID': ['#...anotherID']
}
//Referred through:
namespace['hist_someID'][0]; //returns '#...ID'
```

Comment: will this give me four arrays or just one?

Comment: ah, I did not notice the [] in first suggestion. That would also work I guess. How would I access the nested arrays entries? nameSpace[name][0]?

Comment: `namspace[index][0]`, where *index* is a number. Should I modify the code such that the entries can be accessed through `namespace[name][0]`?

Comment: if you could add as another commented out option, that would be perfect! Then I can play around with both variations. THANKS!